# Image binding to Silverlight treeview controll

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I'm new to silverlight environment,I just want to know where to store the Images folder in a silverlight application so that i can make use of images in it with my treeview control??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a directory at the root level in your Silverlight project, for instance named `Assets`, `Resources` or `Images`.

Then, in your XAML code, set the source of your image by specifying the **relative** path of your image. [Here's an example.](http://angstrey.com/index.php/2010/08/02/how-to-add-an-icon-to-a-button-control-in-silverlight-from-a-resource/)

Comment: @Ajay you're welcome. If you think this answer was helpful, you could consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).